# SQL: count the number of ages in each car

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that looks like the following:

| car_id | ages |
| --- | --- |
| bmw_4523 | 34 |
| civic_1217 | 18 |
| tlx_3498 | 23 |
| bmw_4523 | 45 |
| accord_5678 | 54 |
| bmw_4523 | 22 |
| tlx_3498 | 42 |

So the idea of this table is that for each car_id, there are drivers with specific ages who drive those cars. What I am trying to do, is to count the number of ages in those cars, as well the minimum and maximum ages. For example, I am trying to get a table similar to below:

| car_id | age_count | max | min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bmw_4523 | 3 | 45 | 22 |
| civic_1217 | 1 | 18 | 18 |
| tlx_3498 | 2 | 42 | 23 |
| accord_5678 | 1 | 54 | 54 |

Could you please show how it can be achieved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you had a second car_id bmw_4523 age 34, would that make age_count 4?  or do you just want to count distinct ages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the results by `car_id` and use the count, min and max functions:

```
SELECT
    car_id,
    COUNT(ages) as age_count,
    MAX(ages) as max,
    MIN(ages) as min,
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY car_id
```

Comment: He probably is looking for the unique ages, in which case you want COUNT(DISTINCT ages)

Answer (score 0):

The following query will help you

```
SELECT car_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(ages)) as age_count, MAX(ages) as max, MIN(ages) as min FROM car GROUP BY car_id;
```